# Run a additional uninstall script with setuptools

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, command-line, setuptools

So, I'm writing a simple command-line Python app that maintains some user data. I thought to implement setuptools to make the build and distribution process easier, but I can't find a good solution to manage the user files.

It is easy enough to create a user directory in `/etc/appname`, but when a user wants to uninstall my application, presumably with:

```
sudo pip uninstall appname
```

It won't remove the `/etc/appname` directory holding the users. It'll only remove the `.egg` file.

Is there a way to specifiy in `setup.py` a script that will run when uninstall is called, so I can manually remove the directories I've created?

Or is there an option to have setuptools create a data directory for the purpose of read and writing to files from the application and not just read-only config files?

Comment: You may consider creating packages for linux instead. I have not been able to do it too (using pip command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a proper way to manage dynamic files with setuptools, so I used a Makefile. It creates the directories for the program to reference, then runs setuptools to gather pip packages and install the script to `/usr/bin`.

```
install:
    mkdir -p ~/.appname/users
    sudo python setup.py install
    cp -u appname/users/* ~/.appname/users

uninstall:
    sudo rm -rf ~/.appname
    sudo pip uninstall appname
```